# Derivative and Credit Risk Modelling

Tags: derivatives, credit-risk, risk-models, quants, credit-derivatives

I am looking at acquiring a system to help with multi-instrument modelling. Across the spectrum Equity/FI/Swap/Repo/CDS/FxSwap/Forward/Future/etc for vanilla and more complex derivatives. The modeling is all the way from instrument creation and financial modelling for a deal through to xVA , Credit Risk , E/P-FE , the list is obviously long. I have recently had the pleasure of seeing some implementations of a system called FINCAD and another called TriOptima. I was hoping someone might have had experience with one the other or both and could deliver an option as to their experience and ability / flexibility / coverage / usage of the systems?